# Capturing input from a serial port into a MySQL database in java

Tags: java, mysql, serial-communication

```
  public static void insert (String signal)
{   System.out.println("-------- MySQL JDBC Connection Testing ------------");

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
 System.out.println("MySQL JDBC Driver Registered!");
    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        connection = DriverManager
        .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/activation","root", "piisimba");

        if (connection != null) {
        System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
       } else {
        System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
        }
     try
   {
       String query = "INSERT INTO `test1`( `Time`, `Signal`) VALUES (now(), 'hallosignal');";

        // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
       PreparedStatement preparedStmt2 = connection.prepareStatement(query);

       // execute the preparedstatement
        preparedStmt2.executeUpdate(query);
        connection.close();
   }catch (Exception e)
     {
       System.out.println("exception caught");
     }
 }

    catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
        {
          System.out.println("exception caught");
        }
}
public void run() {

   String s ="";
   try {
     int c = 0;
     while( ( c = System.in.read() ) > -1 ) {

       this.out.write( c );
       s=s+c;
    } 


      System.out.println("s = " + s);
      insert(s);
   }

  catch( IOException e ) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }

 } }
```

I am using a SerialPort with the run()method above .This method sends a specific signal to the port and i need a way to read this signal and insert it in a mysql database. That is why i created a method insert that creates a connection to the database and takes this signal string as an input and inserts it. This method works on its own. However when i call it in my run method no changes happen to the database. Can anyone help me with this problem.

Comment: Change `preparedStmt2.executeUpdate(query);` to `preparedStmt2.executeUpdate();`

Comment: You are sure that the method insert is called?